# c++ header file issue

Tags: c++, networking

I am working on a network sniffer and I need to use the "ws2ipdef.h" header file to parse the information. I am using Codeblocks version 17.12 and I am having the following problem.

Error: ws2ipdef.h. There is no such file or directory.

I tried to use #ifndef _READERCOMMUNICATION_H, but it failed. What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Add some code here to show the way you have included the header. How should we know what exactly the source of your problem is?

Comment: Since you are using Codeblocks, are you using MinGW? ws2ipdef.h seems to be a header file from Win32.